# C++ How do I cast from 1 template class to another?

Tags: c++, templates, casting

I have a class which I *intend to use* with either the type `float` or `double`. As far as I am aware, there is no way to restrict template options, so perhaps I might be doing something dangerous here?

```
template<class T>
class A
{
    A(T arg) { _data = arg; }

    T _data;
}

typedef A<float> A_f;
typedef A<double> A_d;
```

How can I do the following?

```
int main()
{
    A_f f(3.1415);
    A_d d(3.1415);
    f = (A_f)d;
}
```

IE: Cast the class containing data of type double to the class containing data of type float.

Edit: This doesn't seem to be going anywhere, so I tried playing around with this, but obviously I have no idea what to do here so it doesn't compile...

```
template<class T>
class A
{
    friend                    // Intention is for T to be double here
    A<float> operator A<float>(const A<T> input);
}

A<float> operator A<float>(const A<double> input)
{
    return A<float>(input._data);
}
```

Maybe this helps explain what I want to achieve?

Second Edit for Adam:

```
return A<float>((float)input._data);
```

Is this better?

Comment: Exactly the same way as you'd do it if you didn't use templates.

Comment: @n.m. That does not answer the question

Comment: @n.m. I tried googling it, I haven't found the relevant info

Comment: I'm sorry I misread the question completely, disregard what I've said.

Comment: @n.m. Ok                         (7morecharacterstogo)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `std::enable_if` to only allow certain types :

```
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

// Our catch-all is not defined, so will not compile
// Could also be made to print a nice error message
template<typename T, typename Sfinae = void> class A;

// Ok if T is float or double
template<typename T>
class A<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, float>::value
                                || std::is_same<T, double>::value>::type>
{
    // Your class here
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a; // FAILS
    A<float> b; // Ok
    A<double> c; // Ok

    return 0;
}
```

Then you just need to define a conversion operator in your class for the cast to work.

Answer (score 1):

Do not cast, but provide one (and only one) implicit conversion constructor or conversion operator. In your case it might be as trivial as `operator T () const { return _data; }`

Comment: Should this be implemented as an external (friend?) member function? In which case, what are the arguments and return values?

Comment: @user3728501 just an inline member function (operator), it's too trivial

Answer (score 1):

I'll second the arguments that you should not cast like that, but if you insist, add a templated copy constructor:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
public:                                 // add this
    A(T arg) { _data = arg; }

    template <class U>                  // add this
    A(A<U> arg) { _data = arg._data; }  // add this

    T _data;
}
```

This will then allow conversions from `A<U>` to `A<T>` as long as `U` is implicitly convertible to `T`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Are you trying to write a type conversion operator? This answer makes your original code compile.

Comment: @user3728501 I edited my answer to make it clear what I mean. That makes your original `f = (A_f)d;` line work.

Comment: Ah okay - can you explain why I shouldn't cast via this method?

Comment: The main reason is that what you describe is not a cast, it's a type conversion. The way it's written, you're also using an implicit `operator=`. It's not a very clean way to convert.

Comment: Also note that there are data integrity implications of converting between the types you're interested in. Such conversions should be used both carefully and sparingly.

Comment: I don't know what the application of this code is, but unless you're using GPUs or are very constrained by space, you should be using only `double`.

Comment: Why do you think I should only be using double?!?

Comment: The default floating-point type is `double`. Unless you have a good reason to use `float`, you should be using `double`. Note that the standard library's math functions didn't have float versions until C99.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to customize a class based on the type you provide it. The technique is called 'template specialization'

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    void print_my_type() { 
        cout << "Generic template instance" << endl; 
    }

    explicit operator A<int>() const {
        cout << "Casting to int" << endl;
        return A<int>();
    }
};

template <>
class A<int> {
public:
    void print_my_type() { 
        cout << "Class templated with an int" << endl; 
    }

    explicit operator A<double>() const {
        cout << "Casting to double" << endl;
        return A<double>();
    }
};

int main() {
    A<double> a;
    A<int> b;

    a.print_my_type();
    b.print_my_type();

    a = static_cast<A<double>>(b);

    return 0;
}
```

You should not cast objects like that. If you intend to have an object that you want to cast to another. You should provide it an `operator A()` method so it can handle conversions gracefully

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the point of templates? You have to write the class out again for each type?

Comment: @n.m. It's useful info though.

Comment: Lots of templated classes are specialized this way. Like `std::unordered_map` . By the time your code is run there are no templated classes. All references to template types have been resolved @n.m. OP asked "As far as I am aware, there is no way to restrict template options" so it does answer it to an extent. Also i also provided an answer to the implicit "How to cast correctly from one class to another"

Comment: I don't see your answer to the second part. The point being this destroys the point of templates though? So why would anyone choose to write code in this way?

Comment: Sometimes you want a templated class to respond to a specific type in a certain way. For example for an `unordered_map` you could specialize it so that when the user provides a `string` as the key it would do the table lookup in another way then when the user provides an `int` as the key. The point of this is that the implementation is abstracted from the user. So that he/she does not have to worry about selecting different implementations when using a different template argument. That is done automatically. Try refreshing the page?

Comment: Ah I see why this is done for something like `unordered_map` but I don't think it makes sense for what I'm trying to do here - still thanks for making me aware of this possibility.

Comment: Sorry my bad I thought I edited the answer but I hadn't.. Take a look at it now haha what you want should be there now

Answer (score 0):

Example with template conversion operator + static_assert for type verify:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b01010ea5f02aee

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template < typename T > class TD; // type visualiser

template<class T>
class A
{
    public:
    A(T arg) { _data = arg; }

    template<typename D>
    operator A<D>() {
      static_assert(std::is_same<D, float>::value || std::is_same<D, double>::value, "double/floats allowed only");
      //TD<D>();  // D is float here
      return static_cast<D>(_data);
    }

    T _data;
};

typedef A<float> A_f;
typedef A<double> A_d;
typedef A<int> A_i;

int main() {
   A_f f(3.14151);
    A_d d(3.14152);

    std::cout << f._data << std::endl;
    std::cout << d._data << std::endl;    

    f = (A_f)d;
    //f = (A_i)d; // static assertion here

    std::cout << f._data << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[edit]

```
template<class T>
class A
{
public:
   A(T arg) { _data = arg; }

  template<typename D>
  operator A<D>() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<D, float>::value || std::is_same<D, double>::value, "double/floats allowed only");
    //TD<D>();  // D is float here
    return A<D>(static_cast<D>(_data));
  }

  T _data;
};
```

Comment: Either I don't understand the syntax of this or your line `return static_cast<D>(_data);` doesn't make any sense - surely this returns a type `D` not an `A<D>`?

Comment: @user3728501 it was making use of implicit constructor - temporary was being constructed and returned. I have updated answer with explicit construction.